# Trigger $.fancybox.init() after appending the script to the head

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have an API which works appending the fancybox script to the head tag of the client's web page, but obviously this happens after the dom is ready, so the init function of fancybox is not called
In fancybox.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.init();
});
```

I've tried changing it to :

```
$(document).bind('ready', function() {
    $.fancybox.init();
});
```

and then triggering the dom ready function in different ways (one by one):

```
$(document).trigger("ready");
$().trigger("ready")
$().ready();
```

I've also tried calling the init function when the script is loaded:

```
$.fancybox.init();
```

Nothing seems to work.
I'm sure that the fancybox.css, the fancybox.js and even mousewheel.js and easing.js are loaded in the documment before trying all that, I also added a timeout to be sure.
So the question is, how can the fancybox plugin be initialized after appending the js to the head tag?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to call `$.fancybox.init();` but just initialize the proper selector after the fancybox script has been loaded so I would try within the API something like :

```
if (!jQuery.fn.fancybox){
    // fancybox is not loaded
    jQuery.getScript("{path}/jquery.fancybox.js"); // you may need to change the path
    setTimeout(function(){
        // init fancybox selector
        jQuery(".selector").fancybox();
    }, 100); // delay selector initialization
} else {
    // fancybox script is ready so initialize (re-init) selector
    jQuery(".selector").fancybox();
};
```